# Android to Chrome Options

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I need to pass a string from an android device to chrome (any chrome device with the same account). At the moment I'm doing it by using bookmarks, as they sync with each other if you have the same google account.. Then I just put a listener in the chrome extension for any created bookmarks..

It's a bit slow, and I think its because my phone syncs in intervals rather than immediately.. I have a couple of questions:
1) Is there a way of forcing the sync on my android device, so it syncs sooner? 
2) I could use sync.storage but I'm not sure whether this is available on androids end, I have researched but havent come across this.. Does anyone know whether it is possible?

Comment: Interesting question. Observation: Chrome Extensions are not available for mobile, so you can't use extension APIs. However, you can use Chrome Apps to make a separate app. I doubt it will fit your use case though. Probably your best bet is to use a separate server + maybe GCM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chrome storage sync apis are not available on mobile (as of april 2015). I tried something similar a few months ago using too bookmarks (from chrome to phone). You cant force the sync. There are alternatives. Ive used google spreadsheets for that before. Create one on the user's drive. The extension ca read the sheet with chrome identity (user must be signed in thou, or roll your own oauth)